# Replace, trim and then add leading 0's for derived column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a derived column, that I generate from a field 'BANK_REF' that I would like to remove any dash's and spaces from, and then pad it with leading 0's up to 10 characters. The following handles removing the dash's and spaces:

```
REPLACE(TRIM(BANK_REF), "-","")
```

The following add's the leading 0's:

```
(DT_WSTR,6)REPLICATE("0",6 - LEN(BANK_REF)) + BANK_REF
```

Combining the two I get:

```
(DT_WSTR,6)REPLICATE("0",6 - LEN(REPLACE(TRIM(BANK_REF), "-",""))) + REPLACE(TRIM(BANK_REF), "-","")
```

Which achieves what I am after, however it seems inefficient because I duplicate the replace/trim sections. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
select right(replicate("0", 10)+REPLACE(TRIM(BANK_REF), "-",""), 10)
```

I'm not sure if you will notice the difference in efficiency.  Generally SQL queries are dominated by I/O rather than in-memory operations.

Comment: SSIS doesn't accept this as an expression. I assume you meant replace instead of repliace? Either way it goes 'red' but doesnt show an error message unfortunately.

Comment: Ignore my last message. Realised that it should be replicate and that the 0 needs to be in double quotes.